# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.deploy.ServletDef

Tags: tomcat

i when i launch a serveur tomcat 7.0.57
have an error :

> oct. 04, 2023 5:38:21 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
> GRAVE: End event threw exception
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.deploy.ServletDef
> at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
> at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.callMethod1(IntrospectionUtils.java:846)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetNextRule.end(SetNextRule.java:201)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1060)
> at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:609)
> at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1782)
> at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2967)
> at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
> at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
> at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841)
> at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
> at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
> at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
> at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1555)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.parseWebXml(ContextConfig.java:1843)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.getDefaultWebXmlFragment(ContextConfig.java:1498)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1257)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:889)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5416)
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1263)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1948)
> at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

i don't know why ?
jre : jdk1.8.0_102,
tomcat : 7.0.57

i try search why my server don't launch.
but no success at this moment if you can help or have an idea thanks for advance.

Comment: These patch levels are really old. Have you tried updating them as a start? This message makes it look like your existing Tomcat installation is itself broken in some way.

Comment: I can't beacause it's a very old application. I have try remove my tomcat and purge but already same error, have other dev Who run this application with this server version and this jdk.